# Prove that sets don't intersect

Tags: computer-science, computational-mathematics

I am trying to solve a computer algorithm problem that boils down to solving the following. I would appreciate some mathematician assistance on the proof. So here goes:

Having:

**Set $S$** - rational numbers that can be represented as **$n/d$**, where **$d$** is such that **$\lg_2 d \in \Bbb Z$**, and **$n \in \Bbb Z$**

**Set $A$** – subset of **$S$** where **$\lg_4d \in\Bbb Z$** (Ex.: $n/4, n/16, n/64$)

**Set $B$** - the rest of numbers from set **$S$**, that are not in **$A$** (Ex.: $n/2, n/8, n/32$)

**Set $A'$** - set where every member is **$l + m$**, where **$l\in A, m \in A$**

**Set $B'$** - set where every member is **$j + k$**, where **$j\in B$**, **$k\in S$** (either in $A$ or in $B$)

Prove (or disprove) that **$A'$** and **$B'$** don't intersect.

Comment: Think about bit patterns in the binary expansion of numbers.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thanks for your comment. Sure, I can visualize the patterns, but I still cannot grasp if that proves or disproves the above if the numbers are in denominators and fractions are added. Please elaborate further.

Comment: $\lg_2 d \in\mathbb Z$ is not the same as "$d$ is an even number"... For example, $\lg_2(1)$ and $\lg_2(\frac12)$ are in $\mathbb Z$ but neither $\frac12$ nor $1$ is an even number, and $6$ is an even number, but $\lg_2 6$ is not an integer.

Comment: @5xum Thanks! My mistake, pls see edits.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to the question before edit**

That is, when only $n=1$ is considered.

First, $S$ is the sets of numbers $2^n$ with $n\in\Bbb Z$.
$A$ is the subset of numbers $4^n=2^{2n}$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$, hence $B=S\backslash A$ is the set of numbers $2^{2n+1}$ for $n\in \Bbb Z$.

$A'=A+A$, so these are numbers $2^{2p}+2^{2q}$, with $(p,q)\in \Bbb Z^2$. Likewise, numbers in $B'=B+S$, are of the form $2^{2p+1}+2^{q}$.

Numbers in your sets all have a unique binary representation (they have only one or two binary digits, or bits).

Now, a number in $A$ has either two even bits (by even, I mean an even power of $2$ in the binary representation of the number), either one odd bit (if $p=q$).

A number in $B$ has likewise one or two bits. Either $q=2p+1$ and it has one even bit, either $q\neq 2p+1$ and it has one odd bit and another arbitrary (even or odd) bit.

Conclude.

---

**Answer to the edited question**

You have to assume that $\gcd(n,d)=1$ when $n\neq 0$ (and $0\in S$, of course, with $n=0$), otherwise $A=S$. Thus, either $n$ is $0$ or odd. Notice also that $S$ is the set of numbers that have a finite binary representation (they are all rationals with only powers of $2$ in denominator). Any such rational has a unique representation $n 2^p$ with odd $n$, when it's not $0$.

Then numbers in $A$ are of the form $n 2^{2p}$ with odd $n$, or $0$. And $B$ are numbers of the form $n 2^{2p+1}$, with odd $n$ (and $0\notin B$ since $B=S\backslash A$).

Then $9$ and $7$ are in $A$ (with $d=1$), hence $16\in A'$.
But $2\in B$ and of course $14\in S$, so $16\in B'$.

Of course there are *many* other counterexamples. Are $A'$ and $B'$ equal?

Actually, since $0 \in A$, you have also $A \subset A'$. And since $n 2^{2p}+n2^{2p}=n2^{2p+1}$, you have also $B\subset A'$, thus $A'=S$.

On the other hand, for any number in $x\in S$, you have also $x-2 \in S$, ans since $2 \in B$, that means $x=2+(x-2) \in B'$. Hence $S \subset B'$, and $B'=S$.

So $A'=B'=S$.

Comment: My apologies, your answer was lightning fast (thank you for that), but I forgot to mention that numerator is any integer (please see edit), does your answer still apply?

Comment: @LexPodgorny I edited the answer.

Comment: Would you consider this still be the case if we assume that all n/d < 1?

Comment: @LexPodgorny Maybe you could settle once and for all for what you really want to ask :-) I didn't check everything, but you could use $x-2^{2k+1}$ for a suitable $k$.

Comment: My apologies for making you do the double work, as I am not a mathematician, I have to rely on minds like yours to get me to the other side. The actual problem is in a theoretical and completely new way of low level computer data processing, and as I go along I try to narrow it down. I am afraid without your help I would not be able to plug that in.